# Need to capture user entry into jquery chosen input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen

There is no id for the input where the user search text is typed.  I want to capture this and not populate the chosen dropdown until I have three characters entered into that box.

I don't need help with the later, just the former.

Comment: Show us some code. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be nice...

Comment: Is there anything unique about this input in the attributes? Or is it just <input type="text"/>

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, but it really depends on the exact markup of your `input` element. You could select by class, name, or really anything else for that matter, if you are crafty enough.

If **any** one of the following attributes are present:

```
<input id="someId" class="someClass" name="someName" value="someValue" />
```

### [Id Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('input#someId')
```

### [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('input.someClass')
```

### [Attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

#### Name

```
$('input[name="someName"]')
```

#### Value

```
$('input[value="someValue"]')
```

---

There are other ways, but they wouldn't be as flexible or practical.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is SOME way to identify which input you are selecting. Here's the best fiddle I could come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/6xX6v/1/

```
var keyCount = 0;
var inputLength;

$("input").keypress(function() {
    inputLength = $(this).val().length + 1;
    keyCount = inputLength;

    if (keyCount === 3) {
        $("#popthree").append("<option>What are you talking about</option>");
    }
});
```